# LINQ, Getting the next and previous record in my table (I'm Confused)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

So this is my first time using LINQ and I'm liking it so far... However for some reason I can only get the next record once in my table and I'm not sure why it won't keep going with my event.

```
  /*var next = (from a in dc.Employees
                       where a.PrimaryID > Convert.ToInt16(PrimaryID.Text) &&
                       a.PrimaryID < Convert.ToInt16(PrimaryID.Text)+2 select a);*/
```

I know my above works, however it's using a condition assuming the order in the primary key is not missing a record. So if I delete out a record it won't work anymore so I went to try the "Skip.().Take()" methods.

```
    var next = from a in dc.Employees.Skip(1).Take(1) select a;

    FirstNameEmpBox.DataContext = next;
    LastNameEmpBox.DataContext = next;
    StatusEmpBox.DataContext = next;
```

This does work, however only 1 time. So on my click event it jumps to the next record which is awesome. However if I click my next button again, it just sits on that record and doesn't skip it. I'm not positive what I'm doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fetch the next record from your Employee where the PrimaryId is greater than the one you currently have in the TextBox you could compare with this value and use the FirstOrDefault() method to get the first match:

```
var next = (from a in dc.Employees
            where a.PrimaryID > Convert.ToInt16(PrimaryID.Text)
            orderby a.PrimaryID
            select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

And similarly to get the previous record:

```
var prev = (from a in dc.Employees
            where a.PrimaryID < Convert.ToInt16(PrimaryID.Text)
            orderby a.PrimaryID
            select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have a constant of **1** on the Skip() method of your LINQ query.

Syntactically speaking you're always skipping the first record of your Employee collection and getting the next record after that every time this is executed.

Also, to perform skip and take you would need to change your LINQ query to include the order by clause

You may have to create an int variable to iterate through your Employee collection.

Something like this:

```
var counter = 0; // Manage this counter variable accordingly
var next = (from a in dc.Employees order by a.employee_id select a).Skip(counter).Take(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the next item of a sequence specifing the "id" of the previous item with Linq, then you should first order the sequence for "id", then, you should count the elements of the ordered sequence up to your "id" and so skip this number of elements from your original ordered sequence, finally you have to take only one element from the remaining part of the original ordered sequence, that will be the "next" in the sequence.

For the previous item by the "id" of its next element in the sequence you can make an analagous reasoning inverting the count criterion of the elements to be excluded.

In your specific case try this:

```
var emplOrdered = from a in dc.Employees order by a.PrimaryID 

var next = (from a in emplOrdered)
           .Skip(
                 emplOrdered.Where(a.PrimaryID <= Convert.ToInt16(PrimaryID.Text)).Count()
           ).Take(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var next = (from a in dc.Employees
            where a.PrimaryID > Convert.ToInt16(PrimaryID.Text)
            orderby a.PrimaryID
            select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

The previous record:

```
var prev = (from a in dc.Employees
            where a.PrimaryID < Convert.ToInt16(PrimaryID.Text)
            orderby a.PrimaryID descending
            select a).FirstOrDefault();
```